# The systemd status is active, but the script is not functioning properly

Tags: systemd

Here is the config file:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/shutova.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutova
After=multi-user.target
    
[Service]
User=django
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/django/Shutova_assist/bot.py
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I use

```
python3 bot.py
```

everything works without problems.

When I start systemd:

```
sudo systemctl start shutova
```

The status is active, but I'm not receiving any answers when communicating with the bot.
There are no errors in the log either.

What could be the issue?

Comment: *The status is active* but is the *bot* actually **running**

Comment: If I run through: python3 bot.py
everything works perfectly

Comment: yes, but if you DON'T run that, is the bot running

Comment: no it doesn't work. This is the point of my question. what is done wrong and what needs to be done to make it work

Comment: from what you posted, nothing obvious ... have you considered adding some debugging output to your pythin code, perhaps it may give some clue as to what your code is doing wrong

Comment: That is, you want to say that if the script is executed in interactive mode and not executed in systemd then the problem may be in the code?
 (there are a lot of lines of code, do you really need to show all this? and errors are logged, there are no errors in the console at startup)

Comment: Sorry, I'm thinking like a programmer, rather than whatever it is you are

Answer (score 1):

The one difference I can see is that when it works, you're running it in the directory, but in systemd, you're not.
Also, try starting it after networking in case it needs to communicate externally.

Try the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutova
After=network.target
    
[Service]
User=django
Type=simple
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/Shutova_assist/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 bot.py
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately :(
Maybe there are some other ideas?